# Adding a property to all web workers

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, web-worker

I've created a Firefox extension which provides an `openDb` function to create an SQLite database in the profile folder. My function is working fine. But it doesn't work in
a web worker(HTML5), the function isn't defined there.

My `chrome.manifest` file for your reference:

```
component {12345678-1234-5678-abcd-12345678abcd} components/dblay.js
contract @goo.com/gftdb;1 {12345678-1234-5678-abcd-12345678abcd}
category JavaScript-global-property openDB @goo.com/gftdb;1
```

How do I define my function in the web workers as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain that you cannot add global properties to web workers, all the existing options (`javascript-global-property` category, `content-document-global-created` and `document-element-inserted` observer notifications) merely let you adjust the global scopes attached to documents. Even if there *were* a way to do this, it wouldn't help you: it would require your XPCOM component to be accessed from different threads because each web worker has its own thread. JavaScript in Firefox is no longer thread-safe however, you would get crashes if you tried this. So IMHO what you are trying to do isn't doable with a JavaScript-based extension.